# create unique slug django

Tags: python, django, unique, slug

I have a problem with creating unique slugs using django models. I want to allow the admin user to change the slug from the edit page in the admin. When a slug already exists there should be "slug + _1", "slug + _2" etc. Also when a new page is created and there is no slug given the slug should be the page title. I have this code but for some reason the admin keeps saying "Page with this Slug already exists." when I add a page with a slug that already exists. Hope somebody can help me

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.id and not self.slug:
        self.slug = slugify(self.page_title)

    else:
        self.slug = slugify(self.slug)

    slug_exists = True
    counter = 1
    slug = self.slug
    while slug_exists:
        try:
            slug_exits = Page.objects.get(slug=slug)
            if slug_exits == slug:
                slug = self.slug + '_' + str(counter)
                counter += 1
        except:
            self.slug = slug
            break
    super(Page, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Do you mean to write `self.slug = self.slug + '_' + str(counter)` instead of `slug = self.slug + '_' + str(counter)`?

Comment: No its overwriting the var `slug` so it can search for page_1 or page_2 etc. When it's not found the except should give `self.slug` a slug.

Comment: This is not an exact answer to your question, but might be worthwhile to check out: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-autoslug

Comment: Thanks, this is even better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. Didn't test it myself. But it should give you the idea.

```
import re
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.id: # Create
        if not self.slug: # slug is blank
            self.slug = slugify(self.page_title)
        else: # slug is not blank
            self.slug = slugify(self.slug)
    else: # Update
        self.slug = slugify(self.slug)

    qsSimilarName = Page.objects.filter(slug__startswith='self.slug')

    if qsSimilarName.count() > 0:
        seqs = []
        for qs in qsSimilarName:
            seq = re.findall(r'{0:s}_(\d+)'.format(self.slug), qs.slug)
            if seq: seqs.append(int(seq[0]))

        if seqs: self.slug = '{0:s}_{1:d}'.format(self.slug, max(seqs)+1)

    super(Page, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Three problems in your code.

1. The first `else` means either `self.id` or `self.slug` is NOT blank. So if `self.id` is NOT blank and `self.slug` is blank, `self.slug` will not get a value.
2. `slug_exits == slug` will always be False, because `slug_exits` is a Model object and `slug` is a string. **This is why you get the error!**
3. You did a query in the loop, which may cause lots of hits to the DB.